# How to do URL rewriting in Apache through Chef?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, chef-infra

I've made a cookbook in Chef to install a web application, Apache and PHP.
This web application has a PHP document that clients access in this URL:

```
 http://localhost/www-app/ClientFE
```

With this I have a problem. By default PHP will only interpret documents that have a PHP extension, and as my URL doesn't have it, it gets interpreted as text. I can't change the file's extension because the client (which is also software) should not be modified.

What I want to accomplish is to make PHP interpret that document, and for what I've investigated it can be accomplished in three ways at least: configure appropriately PHP, create an alias, create a rewrite rule.

First: I could configure PHP to interpret the desired document:

```
<FilesMatch "/www-app/ClientFE">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Second: I could do it through mod_write (I would have to rename the fill in the web app, which is also acceptable for me):

```
RewriteCond ^/www-app/ClientFE /www-app/ClientFE.php
```

Third: I could do it with mod_alias in a similar fashion than mod_rewrite.

The 3 are good for me, but my problem is: how to do them with Chef ? I haven't been able to find useful docs about it, and I have already tried to put this in my recipe (I found them around the Internet but they haven't worked):

```
apache_rewrite do
    source "/www-app/ClientFE"
    target "/www-app/ClientFE.php"
end
```

and this

```
apache_module "alias" do
    source "/www-app/ClientFE"
    target "/www-app/ClientFE.php"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people in my company suggested 2 valid solutions:

1. Put the configuration in a .htaccess inside my web application. This works for me and allows to use the alternatives I mentioned above.
2. Do nothing! It happens that the Multiviews option in the Apache2 cookbook is enabled by default, and it allows Apache to resolve URL `http://localhost/A` as `http://localhost/A.php`  .... I mean, if Apache is asked about file A, and it doesn't find it, then it will search for A.php instead.

From the two, I chose the later, and yes, it works. It wasn't working before because in my many attempts I created both A and A.php and in that case the Multiviews has no effect.

Comment: Also, I found that if you try to access: http://localhost/A/B/C but there is no folder A in the root, but instead the file A.php in the root exists, then that script A.php will be called in place :O